# String value to replace using regex in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have Notepad++ text editor and have the SQL script file that has many `INSERT` statements, exported from a table. There is a column `TIMESTAMP` in every row with value like this `to_timestamp('08-NOV-13 11.51.51.480570000 AM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM')`.

I need to create a script and replace the above value with `current_timestamp` so all `to_timestamp('08-NOV-13 11.51.51.480570000 AM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM')` like values will be replaced with `current_timestamp`.

Also, let me know if there is any online site available to do do this conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/3) is very ideal for your needs.

Open Sublime Text, copy your input onto the text area, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, and input the following pattern:

```
to_timestamp\([^)]+\)
```

in the "Find What" text box. Now enter "current_timestamp" (without quotes) in the "Replace with" text box, then press "Replace" or "Replace All" and it's done.

Answer (score 0):

Following regex should match your `to_timestamp()` calls, try using it as find/replace pattern.

```
to_timestamp\('[0-9]{2}-[A-Z]{3}-[0-9]{2} (?:[0-9]{2}.){3}[0-9]{9} [AMP]{2}','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM'\)
```